# Error: Unknown Filesystem HELP!

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem

Ok, I am new to Ubuntu and know almost no terminology and don't know a whole lot about computers. So I wanted to install ubuntu so i burned it onto a flashdrive and when I tried booting it I got,

Remove disks or other media.
Press any key to restart

error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue>

Ok so I have no clue what to do, I can't boot from my hard drive, as if it thinks I still have my flash drive in or i think that's what it's doing. I did have windows 7 and trying to boot that is not working. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new startup disk and try again. If you have access to an Ubuntu machine, Startup Disk Creator works well for creating a bootable USB drive.